# $context.Web not working, even when loaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I cant seem to get my CSOM powershell to work with SharePoint Online any more, everything I try to initialise tells me it hasnt been requested?

Connect-SPOSite (Personal Module)

```
$location = "C:\Users\colin.cook\Dropbox\FluidSharePoint\Scripts\SharePointOnline\Lib"
    $files =  get-childItem -LiteralPath $location | select Name
    $files | % {
        $file = $location + "\" + $_.Name
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$file") | out-null  
    }

function global:Connect-SPOSite { 
[CmdletBinding()] 
param ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)]
    $Url
)

begin {

} 

process {         
    if ($global:spoCred -eq $null) { 
        $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your credentials to log into SharePoint Online:" 
        $global:spoCred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($cred.UserName, $cred.Password) 
    } 


    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $Url 
    $context.Credentials = $spoCred 

    if (!$context.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) { 
        Write-Host "Connected to site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green 
    } 
    return $context 
} end { 

} 
}
```

Connection

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ctx = Connect-SPOSite "*****"
Connected to site: '*****'

PS C:\Windows\system32> $ctx


Web                          : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web
Site                         : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site
RequestResources             : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RequestResources
FormDigestHandlingEnabled    : True
ServerVersion                :
Url                          : <Removed for Security>
ApplicationName              : .NET Library
ClientTag                    :
DisableReturnValueCache      : False
ValidateOnClient             : True
AuthenticationMode           : Default
FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo :
Credentials                  : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials
WebRequestExecutorFactory    : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DefaultWebRequestExecutorFactory
PendingRequest               : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest1
HasPendingRequest            : True
Tag                          :
RequestTimeout               : 180000
StaticObjects                : {[Microsoft$SharePoint$SPContext$Current,  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RequestContext]}
ServerSchemaVersion          :
ServerLibraryVersion         :
RequestSchemaVersion         : 15.0.0.0
TraceCorrelationId           :

PS C:\Windows\system32> $web = $ctx.Web
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ctx.Load($web)
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
PS C:\Windows\system32> $web
format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
requested.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNotInitializedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is trying to access all properties and also tries to enumerate some colletions of `$web` (which have not been loaded - this is where your error occurs...).

Try not to "dump" everything. Try `$Web.Title` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use CSOM within your PowerShell scripts, you first need to download the Office Developer Tools based on your visual studio version.This package contains the client DLLs components for SharePoint Online.

- Check the following links to download Office Developer Tools

  - [Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)
  - [Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/15/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)
- load the Clients DLL installed with the Office Developer tools on our local machine.
- Try this

> ```
> Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
>     Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
>
> $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("SharePointSiteURL")
>
> $Web = $Ctx.Web
> ```

Or load assembly file like this

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("SharePointSiteURL")
```

Comment: Thanks, I already load everything and make the connection separately in a module, the $ctx is a return of that which you can see above when I query $ctx but then when I try and initiate anything beyond that it seems to go and do some work but then I get the error shown in my question, I will edit my answer with the connection module.